# Why socketIo is connecting multiple times for single client?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

> **Server code Console logging User connected message every second for single client connection**

```
    import express from "express"
    import http from "http"
    import cors from "cors" 
    import dotenv from "dotenv"
    import movieRoute from './routes/movieRoute.js'
    import ContentRoutes from "./routes/ContentRoute.js"
    import userRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes.js"
    import connectDB from "./config/db.js"
    import axios from "axios"
    const app = express()
    const server = http.createServer(app)
    dotenv.config()
    connectDB()


    const io= socketIo(server)


    app.use(cors())
    app.use(express.json())

    io.on("connection",socket=>{
    console.log("user connected")
})
 
    app.use("/api/users",userRoutes)
    app.use("/api/content",ContentRoutes)
    app.use('/api/movie',movieRoute)

    app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    
    res.send("APi is running")
   })

   const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
    server.listen(PORT,console.log(`Server listening in port ${PORT}`))
```

> React Code Match here changes only one time but myserver is console logging the message userConnected simutenously

```
   let socket
  useEffect(()=>{
      socket= io("http://localhost:5000")
  },[match])
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set it only once time ?

```
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null)

  useEffect(()=>{
      if (socket === null) {
         setSocket(io("http://localhost:5000"))
      }
  },[match])
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it's not working